# How to update the value of a unique column when that value already exists in another row?

Tags: mariadb

Let's say I have the following MariaDB table, the values in "role" must be unique or null:

```
id    |    role   |   name
-----------------------------
1     | null      | David
2     | spy       | Mike
3     | detective | Alan
4     | null      | George
```

I'd like to achieve the following state:

```
id    |    role   |   name
-----------------------------
1     | null      | David
2     | spy       | Mike
3     | null      | Alan
4     | detective | George
```

I know this can be done by first updating the role of 3 to null and then updating the role of 4 to "detective".

But is it possible to achieve this result with just one query?

Comment: Can a person have 2 roles?  Can a role be played by two people?

Comment: @RickJames No, a person can 1 or 0 roles. A role is unique, so a certain role may belong to only one person.

Answer (score 1):

The following is possible in MySQL 8, but I don't know if it works for MariaDB as well:

You can create an `UPDATE` query, which uses [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) to calculate the correct value for the `role` column based on the `name` or `id` field. You have to use `ORDER BY` in the `UPDATE` query to ensure that the existing non-null value has to be set to `NULL` before updating the other row, which gets the previous string value. See the [documentation of `UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) about this:

> If an UPDATE statement includes an ORDER BY clause, the rows are updated in the order specified by the clause. This can be useful in certain situations that might otherwise result in an error.

The query might look like this:

```
UPDATE
    assignment
SET
    role = CASE name
        WHEN 'Alan' THEN NULL
        WHEN 'George' THEN 'detective'
    END
WHERE
    name IN ('Alan', 'George')
ORDER BY
    name = 'Alan' DESC, -- Alan first
    name = 'George' DESC; -- George second
```

If you don't know the previous "owner" of the role, you can change the `WHERE` condition and the `CASE` statement to find the row of 'George' and find the row of the owner of the 'detective' role. The query might look like this:

```
UPDATE
    assignment
SET
    role = CASE name
        WHEN 'George' THEN 'detective'
        ELSE NULL
    END
WHERE
    name = 'George' OR -- the target
    role = 'detective' -- the previous owner
ORDER BY
    name = 'George' ASC; -- first row will be the previous owner
                         -- second row will be the target
```

Comment: Hmm, but shouldn't I know who the previous 'detective' is before running the query? I.e. wouldn't I still need two queries - one for finding out who currently has the 'detective' value and one for updating the values?

Answer (score 0):

Let's ponder a 2-table solution:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id ...,        
    name ...,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
)

CREATE TABLE roles (
    role_name ...,
    user_id ... COMMENT "The one user with this role",
    PRIMARY KEY(role_name),
    INDEX(user_id)    -- (or it could be UNIQUE)
)
```

To get the role for a user:

```
SELECT users.name,
       roles.role_name   -- This will be NULL if not assigned to this user
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN roles  USING(user_id)
    WHERE ...;
```

To change who has a role (the original question):

```
UPDATE roles
    SET user_id = ?
    WHERE role = ?;
```